# how to host nodejs api application on azure virtual machine?

Tags: node.js, azure, virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-vm

I am new to Azure virtual machine and in hosting world. I have created a nodejs api application, and now I want to host it on virtual machine. I have create a virtual machine too, but I have no idea on how to host my nodejs project which is on my local system to azure vm. Please can anyone help?

Comment: Unfortunately, as written, this is off-topic as it's very broad and opinion-based. There's really no way to answer this objectively. App deployments can be automated; you can manually install them; etc. There's networking to consider, VM extensions, on and on. Then the option of running your app in an app service instead of a VM. There are just too many possibilities. I suggest starting with documentation about the various services, to make a choice that's right for you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Actually my project is online-ide, so we need virtual machine as compilers can be installed in vm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy `node.js` application to Azure VM we need to have following perquisite :

- Node.js installed on your system (version >= 10.3)
- Azure account
- A CircleCI account
- A GitHub account
- Azure CLI installed on your system (version >= 10)

Then need to Set-up a virtual machine on Azure to run Node.js.

For complete information please refer to this *BLOG* : [***Continuous deployment of Node.js to Azure VM***](https://circleci.com/blog/cd-azure-vm/) & *GitHub:* [***Deploy a Node.js application to Linux Virtual Machines in Azure***](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/virtual-machines-linux-nodejs-deploy.md)

Comment: thanks, but can you please help me more by giving more details. I refered those sites, but it's more complext.

Comment: Hello @jkkCoder, could you please refer to [this](https://reverentgeek.com/hosting-node-js-on-microsoft-azure/) one  more where it has described all the steps similar to above . We need to setup in this way only.